# Узнать разрешение изображения по URL, используя python-2.7

Tags: изображения, url, python-2.7

Имеется список URL'ов картинок форматов jpg, jpeg, png (около 100к шт.). Необходимо без загрузки узнать: не меньше ли это изображение чем 640х480

Например, входная информация у меня хранится в виде: https://www.metropac.com/woeimg/00355976.jpg

P.S. полапатил гугл и попробовал несколько бесполезных вариантов, и пришёл к выводу, что без скачивания не обойтись.

Comment: если содержимое картинок не доступно, то  каким образом информация о картинке известна: в имени файла в урле? в возвращаемых http заголовках? Сервер API предоставляет по запросу мета-информации о картинках? Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос. Нажмите [edit]

Comment: @jfs, в голову приходит решение типа: скачать картинку, узнать о ней всё что нужно, удалить - повторить со следующей и т.д. Может быть такое решение можно реализовать?

Comment: в чём у вас затруднение: как скачать картинку? или как узнать размер, скачанной картинки? [temporarily retrieve an image using the requests library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32853980/4279)

Comment: @jfs, поставить и то, и то на поток, т.к. количество картинок постоянно увеличивается

Comment: начните с кода для одной ссылки. Затем покажите ваши попытки несколько адресов опросить и какие конкретно ошибки возникают. Вот [простой пример кода, как можно параллельно опрашивать ссылки](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27986480/4279)